# How to use regular expression for + and - using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following piece of code which accepts only number form keyboard,

```
function only_numeric(e)
{
    var keynum;
    var keychar;
    var numcheck;
    if(window.event) // IE
    {
        keynum = e.keyCode;
    }
    else if(e.which) // netscape/Firefox/opera
    {
        keynum = e.which;
    }

    //condition for backspace(8) Key
    if(keynum != 8)
    {
        keychar = String.fromCharCode(keynum);
        numcheck = /\d/;
        return numcheck.test(keychar);
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This return only number when user types keyboard,Now I want to use "+" and "-" from keyboard.So How can i use `numcheck = /\d/;` here?

Kindly help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should match \d and - and + : `numcheck = /[-+0-9]/;`